# Using SQL Server/Database Source from Cell Values

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a macro to query SQL data into multiple sheets, and the problem I encounter is that I want to allow the code to reference the SQL server address and database name from cell values (i.e. User inputs which server/database they want to connect and pull data from)

The current code with a fixed server/db name (SQLEXPRESS/Datalogger) is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="DataTable", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database("".\SQLEXPRESS"", ""Datalogger"")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    dbo_DataTable = Source{[Schema=""dbo"",Item=""DataTable""]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    dbo_DataTable"
Sheets.Add.Name = "DataTable"
Sheets("DataTable").Move After:=Sheets("HOME")
```

The area where the user can specify the server/db name would be in cells B1 & B2. So I tried the following code to add as a string, but it's not working:

```
Dim sSqlSvr As String
Dim sSqlDb As String
sSqlSvr = Worksheets("HOME").Range("B1")
sSqlDb = Worksheets("HOME").Range("B2")

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="DataTable", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database(sSqlSvr, sSqlDb)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    dbo_DataTable = Source{[Schema=""dbo"",Item=""DataTable""]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    dbo_DataTable"
Sheets.Add.Name = "DataTable"
Sheets("DataTable").Move After:=Sheets("HOME")
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something here in calling the string. The error is Run-time error '1004'. "Couldn't get data from the Data Model". "The import sSqlSvr matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?"

I guess the its literally looking for a server/db name with sSqlSvr/sSqlDb instead of recognizing as a string... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variable names as literals within the string. You need to escape out of the string to insert the value of the variables into the string:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="DataTable", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database(""" & sSqlSvr & """, """ & sSqlDb & """)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    dbo_DataTable = Source{[Schema=""dbo"",Item=""DataTable""]}[Data]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    dbo_DataTable"
```

Edit: fixed double quotes!

Comment: Something else went wrong, I think its pretty close tho....
Expression.Error: Token Literal expected.
Details:
    let
    Source = Sql.Database(.\SQLEXPRESS, Datalogger),
    dbo_DataTable = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="DataTable"]}[Data]
in
    dbo_DataTable

Missing the "" perhaps? I tried variations such as (" & "sSqlSvr" & ", " & "sSqlDb" & ") and ("" & sSqlSvr & "", "" & sSqlDb & "") but it's not correct.... Expression.Error: The import sSqlSvr matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?

Comment: My bad. The double quotes need escaping in the string. The joys of escaping!